# Hibernate : why createQuery() appends package name to the Entity Name?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to query database from two Different Tables i.e.

```
query = "select rbt.rbtCode, rbt.maskedName, cmas.catId, cmas.maskedName " +
    "from CrbtRbt rbt, CrbtCategoryMaster cmas " +
    "where rbt.playable='Y' and rbt.showOnWeb='Y' and rbt.rbtCode!=0 " +
    "and rbt.catId=cmas.catId";
```

but when I pass this query through `session.createQuery(query);`

It appends package name to the next in coming Entity Name i.e.

```
select rbt.rbtCode, rbt.maskedName, cmas.catId, cmas.maskedName
from CrbtRbt rbt, com.telemune.toolGeneratedPojos.CrbtCategoryMaster cmas
where rbt.playable='Y' and rbt.showOnWeb='Y' and rbt.rbtCode!=0 and rbt.catId=cmas.catId
```

and gives the following Exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CrbtRbt is not mapped [select rbt.rbtCode, rbt.maskedName, cmas.catId, cmas.maskedName from CrbtRbt rbt, com.telemune.toolGeneratedPojos.CrbtCategoryMaster cmas where rbt.playable='Y' and rbt.showOnWeb='Y' and rbt.rbtCode!=0 and rbt.catId=cmas.catId]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:325)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3252)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3141)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:550)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
at com.telemune.generator.TestQuery.select(TestQuery.java:114)
at com.telemune.generator.PojoGenerator.main(PojoGenerator.java:191)
```

**But** if I query the Entities One By One it shows the desired result successfully.

i.e.

```
select rbt.rbtCode, rbt.maskedName
from CrbtRbt rbt
where rbt.playable='Y' and rbt.showOnWeb='Y' and rbt.rbtCode!=0;
```

gives desired result.

Can anyone Explain what I can do?

here is some example code:
**Query Code**

```
 hql = session.createQuery(query);
    hql.setMaxResults( querySchema.getMaxRes() );
    list=hql.list();
```

For information I have done All the Mappings and included all the libraries very carefully no chance of any mistake.

**UPDATE**

As I said I have done the mappings carefully but someone may have doubts so here is the mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.telemune.toolGeneratedPojos.CrbtCategoryMaster" schema="SDP" table="CRBT_CATEGORY_MASTER">
            <id name="catId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="CAT_ID" precision="4" scale="0" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property column="SHOW_IN_SMS" name="showInSms" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="SHOW_ON_WEB" name="showOnWeb" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="PLAYABLE" name="playable" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="STATUS" name="status" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="IMAGE_PATH" name="imagePath" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="DESCRIPTION" name="description" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="MASKED_NAME" name="maskedName" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="IVR_FILEPATH_1" name="ivrFilepath1" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="IVR_FILEPATH" name="ivrFilepath" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="MASKED_NAME_1" name="maskedName1" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class></hibernate-mapping>
```

and for CRBT_RBT:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.telemune.toolGeneratedPojos.CrbtRbt" schema="SDP" table="CRBT_RBT">
            <id name="rbtCode" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="RBT_CODE" precision="10" scale="0" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property column="PLAYABLE" name="playable" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="OTHER" name="other" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="IMAGE_PATH" name="imagePath" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="RBT_ORDER" name="rbtOrder" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="VALIDITY_PERIOD" name="validityPeriod" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="LYRICIST" name="lyricist" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="APPROVED_BY" name="approvedBy" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="PREV_CAT_ID" name="prevCatId" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="RELEASE_YEAR" name="releaseYear" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="COMPOSER" name="composer" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="SHOW_ON_WEB" name="showOnWeb" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="MASKED_NAME" name="maskedName" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="CONTENT_PROVIDER_CODE" name="contentProviderCode" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="CREATE_DATE" name="createDate" type="java.sql.Date" />
            <property column="IVR_FILEPATH" name="ivrFilepath" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="CORP_ID" name="corpId" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="SHOW_IN_SMS" name="showInSms" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="ALBUM_NAME" name="albumName" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="NOKIA" name="nokia" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="STATUS" name="status" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="FILE_PATH" name="filePath" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="REFERENCE_ID" name="referenceId" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="CHARGING_CODE" name="chargingCode" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="RBT_NICK" name="rbtNick" type="java.lang.String" />
            <property column="APPROVAL_DATE" name="approvalDate" type="java.sql.Date" />
            <property column="CAT_ID" name="catId" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="RBT_SCORE" name="rbtScore" type="java.lang.Integer" />
            <property column="ARTIST_NAME" name="artistName" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I don't think there is any mistake in the mapping.

Hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">sdp</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.168.2.127:1521:mastera</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sdp</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="com/telemune/toolGeneratedPojos/CrbtRbt.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/telemune/toolGeneratedPojos/CrbtCategoryMaster.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: can you show mapping from CrbtRbt? ty.

Comment: Do they in the same persistenceContext

Comment: @ HRgiger I don't understand/know **persistenceContext**  can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao I have updated my question please have a look.

Comment: you can retrieve a simple CrbtRbt object? ok sorry...

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao Yes please read the question as a whole i have added there **_ if I query the Entities One By One it shows the desired result successfully._**

Comment: WTF can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml too? maybe a brilliant mind see the mistake...

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao hibernate has nothing to do with it as I said it prints the resultSet successfully every single table. beacuse I am adding the resources at runtime before building the session factory i.e. **configuratio().addResource(mappingResources)**

Comment: @lanMcLaird I am using hibernate-4.0.

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao I have updated the question and hibernate.cfg.xml is there. but ZaoTaoBao hibernate.cfg.xml has nothing to do with it as I said it prints the resultSet successfully every single table. beacuse I am adding the resources at runtime before building the session factory i.e. configuratio().addResource(mappingResources

Comment: @v.ladynev sir please have a look.

Comment: @RomanC take a glance please

Comment: Is there no one to solve the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got this.

```
SessionFactory getSessionFactory(className) {
    try {
         configuration.addResource( className + ".hbm.xml" );
    }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

configuration.configure();
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
```

return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

here is the code to add .hbm.xml file,programatically, for each class while creating session factory.

```
try {
    sessionFactory = ...getSessionFactory(className);
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the problem with this code was that:

**1.** It was building a new session factory for each call(of getSessionFactory(classname)).

**2.** a new session was opened every time.
So, only the mapping of last class added to configuration was added as a resource and that's why its was searching the other classes by appending the packageName to it's name.

**What I did is:** 
I just counted the no of mapping files in the package and added them with the help of a loop in the same session factory.
And it worked.

Here is the way:

```
File file = new File(packageName.replace(".", "/"));
for(File file1 : file.listFiles()){
    if(file1.getName().trim().substring(file1.getName().trim().lastIndexOf("."),
       file1.getName().trim().length()).equalsIgnoreCase(".xml")){
       configuration.addResource( packageName.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + "/" + file1.getName() );
    }
}
```

It was just a silly mistake.